# How to pass extra arguments in selector?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this piece of code

```
class func catchWeightList(catchWeightButton : UIButton, productCatchWeightList:NSArray){
    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))

    let catchWeightVC = CatchWeight.init(nibName: "CatchWeight", bundle: nil,dataSource: productCatchWeightList, catchWeightButton: catchWeightButton)

    if catchWeightVC.view.superview == nil {
        let y =  catchWeightButton.frame.origin.y+catchWeightButton.frame.height+64

        catchWeightVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(catchWeightButton.frame.origin.x, y ,catchWeightButton.frame.width, 90)

        window?.addSubview(catchWeightVC.view)
        window?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    else{
        catchWeightVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        window?.removeGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }


}
class func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    //        catchWeightVC?.view.removeFromSuperview()
    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    window?.removeGestureRecognizer(sender!)
}
```

How to pass catchWeightVC in handleTap?

Comment: You cannot pass it into the handler. Make your methods to be instance methods and just save the view as an instance variable.

Comment: cant do that , need these functions independent of instance

Comment: @Sulthan can i put handleTap inside `class func catchWeightList` ? somehow ?

Comment: add static var to your class. No?

Comment: i used tag on that view `catchWeightVC.view.tag = 1`, and  then in `handleTap` i do `window?.viewWithTag(1)?.removeFromSuperview()`  . Anyways thanks for help guys

Comment: @aishwatsingh Your are using very fragile solutions. I really recommend you to fix your architecture instead of using workarounds and creating unmaintainable code.